# setup font-awesome with webpack

Tags: webpack, font-awesome

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot'
```

I am tring to setup font-awesome with webpack.I got the above errors.

here is my webpack.common.js file:

```
{
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: 'file-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff'
            }
```

once I import :

```
@import '~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss';
```

a lot of module not found. I am sure i installed font-awesome-sass-loader, css-loader, url-loader, file-loader.

Can someone give me a hint what did I miss?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In my [HTML Starter](https://github.com/cichy380/html-starter-bs4-webpack) I am using [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader) with similar Webpack configuration:

```
{
   test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot)(\?[a-z0-9=.]+)?$/,
   loader: 'file-loader',
   options: {
      outputPath: 'fonts',
      name: '[name].[ext]',
   },
   exclude: /node_modules/,
}
```

but I had to configure `publicPath` in [MiniCssExtractPlugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin).loader also:

```
{
   loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
   options: {
      publicPath: '../',
   }
},
```

and I used [resolve-url-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/resolve-url-loader)

---

This is my commit with adding loader for font files: 
https://github.com/cichy380/html-starter-bs4-webpack/commit/285604e0cdcd3ff16ba88fe482f21ad77355ef87